# Angular-emoji not working with ionic project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building an **ionic** app in which **angular-emoji** is going to be use,
but it shows me error

```
Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined
```

problem is that `ionic-bundle.min.js` is **conflict** with angular-emoji...
it works fine without ionic projects...
please help me out...
This is sample code of project where you can try to solve:

https://github.com/sagardalal21/AngularEmoji-IonicApp

Comment: Please add a piece of code where you think problem is.

Comment: I have kept everything same for emoji but when i put same code in ionic it fails to load, I am not sure about where the problem is !